# Hyperledger transaction should have been denied, but went to default rule

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to run my test for my chaincode and this is what I am getting.

```
return useIdentity(aliceIdentity)
        .then(() => {

            // Submit the transaction.
            const transaction = factory.newTransaction('com.james.demo', 'UpdateAppointment');
            transaction.asset = factory.newRelationship('com.james.demo', 'Appointment', '2', '11/2/2017', '08:19','new','3');
            transaction.newValue = '50';
            return businessNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(transaction);

        })
        .should.be.rejectedWith(/does not have .* access to resource/);
```

I get this:

```
AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected with an error matching /does not have .* access to resource/ but it was fulfilled with undefined
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {com.james.demo.UpdateAppointment} tx The sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
function UpdateAppointment(tx, patient, doctor, origAppointment) {

    // Save the old value of the asset.
    var oldValue = tx.asset.value;

    // Update the asset with the new value.
    tx.asset.value = tx.newValue;

    // Get the asset registry for the asset.
    return getAssetRegistry('com.james.demo.Appointment')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {

            // Update the asset in the asset registry.
            return assetRegistry.update(tx.asset);

        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tx));
        });
}
```

This is the rule:

```
rule DoctorHasFullAccessToTheirAssets {
    description: "Allow all participants full access to their assets"
    participant(p): "com.james.demo.Doctor"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "com.james.demo.Appointment"
    condition: (r.doctor.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```

This is appointment

```
asset Appointment identified by appointmentId {
  o String appointmentId
  o String appointmentDate optional
  o String appointmentTime optional
  o String status optional
  --> Doctor doctor optional
  --> Patient owner optional
  o String value optional
}
```

And doctor:

```
participant Doctor identified by npiId {
   o String npiId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}
```

Inside `UpdateAppointment` I have a `console.log` command that isn't being executed, it appears. so I am thinking that my function isn't actually being executed.

Having multiple parameters in my UpdateAppointment, is that incorrect?

How do I get this test to pass?

Comment: I didn't see your modeled transaction ie `com.james.demo.UpdateAppointment` in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your modeled transaction ie `com.james.demo.UpdateAppointment` in your post. But you would just pass the `UpdateAppointment` transaction instance so:

```
function UpdateAppointment(tx) { 
...
}
```

Then reference your patient, doctor (participants) and appointments (Asset listing, for example) via relationships in your transaction definition.

Check out this sample-network logic https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js and also how the relationships are modeled in the transaction (ie may be a similar thing for you: relationship of Appointment to: Patient (appointee and participant), doctor (participant in the appointment), origAppointment (Patient can have one-to-many relationship with appointments as a listing?). Anyway, you know your use case better. Point being, your transaction instance has the means to know who the participants are and what the asset instance is, when the transaction logic is being executed, via the Transaction Processor function - see more here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts.html

hope this helps..